# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'gmail'

Tags: python, django

I am working with `Django`.

my `models.py`:

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I am trying to get a list of `gmail` inside `to` named variable.

in my `views.py`:

```
def submit_report(request, pk):
  admin_obj = Admin.objects.all()
  to = admin_obj.gmail
  print(to)

  return redirect('app:index')
```

but it says error like:

```
Internal Server Error: /submit_report/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\django\hackathon practice\ProjectSurokkhaBeta_1.7\app\views.py", line 532, in submit_report    
    to = admin_obj.gmail
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'gmail'
[12/Jan/2021 09:48:54] "GET /submit_report/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 77827
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuerySet` is collection of objects. You should iterate over it to get `Admin` objects and then access `gmail` from those objects.

```
admin_objs = Admin.objects.all()
for admin_obj in admin_objs:
    to = admin_obj.gmail
    print(to)
```

Comment: I just need one more thing, the `to` variable needs to be a `list` like.... [gmail1, gmail2,......]

Comment: declare `to = []` outside the loop. Inside the loop, replace `to = admin_obj.gmail` with `to.append(admin_obj.gmail)`.